# Recieve all details from a specific column in a html page

Tags: html, get, web-scraping, save, text-files

I'm trying to get & store in a text file all the all addresses from the "address" column in the next page:
http://bitcoinrichlist.com/top100

It should be very simple, but I never worked with something like this before, I always received data from mysql databases or php variables, but never from a html page.

Someone may explain me how should I do this?
Storing the addresses it's easy, fwrite command right to a text file on my server.

But what about receiving the data? How should I do it?

edit:
My question in short is: **How should I save all the addresses from the "address" column in a text file?**

Comment: Can you clarify -- are you in control of this page, is this on your own server? Or are you trying to scrape it from the front-end?

Comment: actually it's a school task, I need to write a 7-12 line code in which I pull date from an internet page. I want to pull all the adressess from the "address" column and save it in a txt file. I don't mind to choose other column, it's just has to be pulling date from a column of an internet page.

Comment: and what language are you using to scrape the site?

Comment: php/javascript.. there isn't any specific request. The only request is the length of the code, it's should be less or equal to 12 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to pull in a web page and then traverse its DOM. Example from their quick start guide:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Once you gather up the elements, loop through them and write out to a file.

Comment: Thanks Josh, but the elements are the same for all the columns. I need to gather up the "address" column, but if i'll use your method it will also save the other columns to my file.